# Selenium×Node.jsでテスト実行すると「NoSuchSessionError: no such session」となりうまくいかない

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, selenium

### 前提・実現したいこと

自社プロダクトで人力で行っているシナリオテストの工数・負荷を削減したく
Selenium×Node.jsでテスト自動化を行おうとしていますが、調査の段階で詰まってしまっています。。。

### 環境

- Mac OS10.12.6
- Node 8.11.1
- Selenium Server 3.12.0
- Selenium WebDriver 4.0.0
- ChromeDriver 2.38

### やったこと

**1. Node.js のインストール**

[公式サイトから](https://nodejs.org/en/)

**2. selenium-webdriverのインストール**

npm経由でインストール

```
$ npm install selenium-webdriver
```

**3. selenium-serverのインストール**

Homebrew経由でインストール

**4. Chromeドライバのインストール**

[ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/)

→ドライバをダウンロードしたらファイルを移動

```
$ mv /Users/username/Downloads/chromedriver ./
$ ls -la
total 31920 
drwxr-xr-x 7 username staff 238 5 24 17:42 . 
drwxr-xr-x+ 55 username staff 1870 5 24 17:42 .. 
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 username staff 11917200 4 20 16:39 chromedriver 
drwxr-xr-x 41 username staff 1394 5 24 16:45 node_modules 
-rw-r--r-- 1 username staff 9367 5 24 16:45 package-lock.json
```

**5. Selenium Server の起動**

バックグラウンドで起動

```
$ selenium-server -port 4444 &amp;
[1] 33415
C02SY1XFGTFJ:selenium username$ 18:04:14.512 INFO [GridLauncherV3.launch] - Selenium build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3'
18:04:14.513 INFO [GridLauncherV3$1.launch] - Launching a standalone Selenium Server on port 4444
2018-05-24 18:04:14.624:INFO::main: Logging initialized @441ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
18:04:14.882 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Welcome to Selenium for Workgroups....
18:04:14.882 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 4444
```

### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

サンプルとなるテストコードを書きます。

```
$ vim sample.js

// WebDriver の初期化
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
// ブラウザの選択
const browser = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();

// ページタイトルの取得
browser.get('http://example.selenium.jp/reserveApp/').then(()=&gt;{
    browser.getTitle().then(title =&gt; console.log('ページタイトル:',title))
});

// ブラウザの終了
browser.close();
browser.quit();
```

上記コードを実行させると、、、

```
$ node sample.js 
(node:13216) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchSessionError: no such session
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552518 (183d19265345f54ce39cbb94cf81ba5f15905011),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/Users/ko-kamenashi/selenium/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:585:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/Users/ko-kamenashi/selenium/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:533:13)
at Executor.execute (/Users/ko-kamenashi/selenium/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:468:26)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
(node:13216) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:13216) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

とエラーになります。
エラーメッセージ「NoSuchSessionError: no such session」等でググると記事は出てくるのですが、
本事象の解決とは至っていません。

### 以上です

お手数ですが皆様のお知恵を拝借できれば幸いです。宜しくお願い致します。